# ASP.NET Core 1.1 Localization Generic Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I'm making a ASP.NET Core 1.1 app and trying to setup localization.

When I make on my `ValuesController` the implementation of `IStringLocalizer` it works fine and localize my resource file.

```
public ValuesController(IStringLocalizer<ValuesController> localizer, IService<BaseEntity> service)
{
    _localizer = localizer;
    _service = service;
}
```

The code above locate my resources at "Resources/Controllers/ValuesController.en-US.resx".

But, when I try to inject the `IStringLocalizer` with a generic service it can't find my resource file.

```
public class Service<T> : IService<T>
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    #region Properties
    protected IRepository Repository { get; set; }
    protected IUnitOfWorkFactory UnitOfWorkFactory { get; set; }
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

    #endregion

    #region Ctor
    public Service(IRepository repository, IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory,
        ILogger<Service<T>> logger, IStringLocalizer<Service<T>> localizer)
    {
        Repository = repository;
        UnitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
        _logger = logger;
        _localizer = localizer;
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't locate my resource at "Resources/Services/Base/Service.en-US.resx"

Any idea on how to do it ?

--- EDIT

MyControl.Api (Startup.cs)

namespace MyControl.Api

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

This line is inside "MyControl.Api", with is in the namespace "MyControl.Api".

The resources folder in this aplication work for "Resources/Controllers"

My services are in namespace "MyControl.Services"

The resources folder in this Project (two projects inside same solution) are

"Resources/Services/Base"

The namespace of my service file is "MyControl.Services.Services.Base"

Comment: By default it should work if path to the resource file is correct. Please add service's namespace and your `services.AddLocalization` call to question.

Comment: Added.

Service.cs namespace > "MyControl.Services.Services.Base"
Resources folder at "MyControl.Services" Project > "Resources/Services/Base"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Explanation**

You're right, the problem is in generic class. Accordingly to the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization) of `ResourceManagerStringLocalizer` (it's default `IStringLocalizer` implementation) - that class contains `_resourceBaseName` private field. The same string also [is used](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization/ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory.cs#L191) to locate resource files as a search path parameter in `ResourceManager` class.

When `IStringLocalizer` is injected into a closed generic type instance, this field is set incorrectly with something like:

> FooProject.Resources.Services.FooService`1[[System.Double, System.Private.CoreLib...

Instead of correct one:

> FooProject.Resources.Services.FooService

You can check the localizer `_resourceBaseName` value in debugger. It's probably a bug and you would open an issue about it on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues.

**Workaround**

It is possible to create a `ResourceManagerStringLocalizer` instance manually. We should take this `baseName` part from a class full name without a csproj-file name and without a class name itself:

Full class name:

> MyCsprojFileName.AnyFolder.SubFolder.FooClass

`baseName`:

> AnyFolder.SubFolder

For the code you provided `baseName` is probably `"Services.Base"`. 
Let's write some code to get it in generic way:

```
public class FooService<T>
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizerFactory _factory;

    public FooService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public IStringLocalizer GetLocalizer()
    {
        var type = typeof(FooService<>);

        string assemblyName = type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        string typeName = type.Name.Remove(type.Name.IndexOf('`'));
        string baseName = (type.Namespace + "." + typeName).Substring(assemblyName.Length).Trim('.');

        var localizer = _factory.Create(baseName, assemblyName);

        return localizer;
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid a "must-have" resources for every class and consequently duplicated messages I've created a holder class "LanguageLocalizer.cs" and just Init all my localizers from that. But, your aswer is right. Thank you very much !