# How to use localization in Asp.Net Core with Generic Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I've worked on Asp.Net Core web application.

I've tried to use localization with my generic controller like this:

```
    public class ManageController<TUser, TKey> : Controller
            where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>, new()
            where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
        {

    private readonly IStringLocalizer<ManageController<TUser, TKey>> _localizer;

    public ManageController(IStringLocalizer<ManageController<TUser, TKey>> localizer)
            {
                _localizer = localizer;
            }

    }
```

Unfortunately this line doesn't work - `IStringLocalizer<ManageController<TUser, TKey>> localizer` - becuase of generic class.

How to use `IStringLocalizer` for this use case?

Comment: which part is not working? it seems ok! you just need `protected IStringLocalizer<ManageController<TUser, TKey>> _localizer`

Comment: Wrong paste my source code, I have this part as well. Problem is that _localizator doesn't work with generic class.

Comment: again what do you mean by doesn't work? is it giving exception? do you have compile time error? do you have runtime error? what is it

Comment: If I use `_localizer["key"]` - it doesn't return correct string from resx file but only put string "key".

Comment: how did you name your resource file? what is the location of it?

Comment: `Resources/Controllers/ManageController.en.resx` - it is works before I've changed the controller to generic version. Another controllers work fine.

Comment: I've solved this issue with this anwer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44342243/943403
Thanks for your effort @Simonare